# How to move json property from one record value into a new one in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I use SQL Server and I need to move `"setting0"` and `"setting1"` from one JSON value into a new JSON value in a new record;

Here is the table structure:

```
userId | setting type | settings
-------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------
id0    | type0        | {"setting0": 0, "setting1": 1, "setting2": 2, "...", "setting100": 100}
```

and I need to get this result:

```
userId | setting type | settings
-------+--------------+---------------------------------
id0    | type0        | {"setting2": 2, "...", "setting100": 100}
id0    | type1        | {"setting0": 0, "setting1": 1}
```

Update:

There are a lot of settings in JSON value with `type0` and due to business logic I need to separate only `setting0` and `setting1` from `type0` and move it to `type1`.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What's the rule for the splitting? I mean why do you move the keys stting0-1 but not setting2 to type1

Comment: thank you; I`ve updated the description, there are a lot of settings in json value with type0, I need to separate only setting0 and setting1 and move it to type1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible approach is to use `VALUES` table value constructor and:

- `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema to extract the `$.setting0` and `$.setting1` key\value pairs from the existing JSON data with the appropriate data types and `FOR JSON` to output the extracted values as JSON.
- `JSON_MODIFY()` with `NULL` as value to delete the `$.setting0` and `$.setting1` keys.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   userID varchar(3),
   settingType varchar(5),
   settings varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO Data (userID, settingType, settings) 
VALUES
   ('id0', 'type0', '{"setting0":0,"setting1":1,"setting2":2,"setting3":3}'),
   ('id1', 'type0', '{"setting0":0,"setting1":1,"setting2":2,"setting3":3,"setting4":4}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.userID, v.settingType, v.settings
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
   -- Existing row
   (
      d.settingType, 
      JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(d.settings, '$.setting0', NULL), '$.setting1', NULL)
   ),
   -- New row
   (
      'type1', 
      (
      SELECT setting0, setting1
      FROM OPENJSON(d.settings) WITH (
         setting0 int '$.setting0',
         setting1 int '$.setting1'
      )
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )
   )
) v (settingType, settings)
```

Result:

```
userID settingType settings
-----------------------------------------------------------
id0    type0       {"setting2":2,"setting3":3}
id0    type1       {"setting0":0,"setting1":1}
id1    type0       {"setting2":2,"setting3":3,"setting4":4}
id1    type1       {"setting0":0,"setting1":1}
```

Comment: @franklin If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **read the table row** you want to get the data from, **remove** the code you want to move, **update** the row and **insert the removed data into a new row**.

Note that you're not getting any detailed information about how to do this if you're not giving more detailed information about your problem.

- What's the **rule for splitting** the data?
- What's the `setting_type`?

Comment: thank you, I`ve updated a description; the rule is separate only setting0 and setting1 from  hundreds of settings in type0. Setting_type its identificator for  selection of settings

Answer (score 0):

The following returns the correct output.  First, for each userID it returns 'setting2' (if it exists) as JSON.  Second, for each userID it modifies the JSON to remove 'setting2' (if it exists).  Something like this

Data

```
drop table if exists #JsonSettings;
go
create table #JsonSettings(
  userID        varchar(12) not null,
  settingType   varchar(12) not null,
  settings      nvarchar(max));

insert #JsonSettings(userID, settingType, settings) values
('id0', 'type0', N'{"setting0": 0, "setting1": 1, "setting2": 2}'),
('id2', 'type0', N'{"setting0": 0, "setting1": 1, "setting2": 2, "setting3": 3}');
```

Query

```
select distinct userId, settingType, 
      (select json_value(settings, '$.setting2') setting2 
                             for json path, without_array_wrapper) settings
from #JsonSettings js
     cross apply openjson(js.settings) oj
where oj.[key]=N'setting2'
union all
select distinct userId, settingType,
       json_modify(js.settings,'$.setting2', null) settings
from #JsonSettings js
     cross apply openjson(js.settings) oj
where oj.[key]=N'setting2'
order by 1, 3 desc;
```

Output

```
userId  settingType settings
id0     type0       {"setting2":"2"}
id0     type0       {"setting0": 0, "setting1": 1}
id2     type0       {"setting2":"2"}
id2     type0       {"setting0": 0, "setting1": 1, "setting3": 3}
```